# Copy to clipboard - Android studio (getString - settextView)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, clipboard

I'm trying to add a "copy" button to a settextview.

Here is my full code:

```
public class activity_tasks extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button_refresh;
    TextView textView;
    TextView textView4;
    private AdView mAdView;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        button_refresh = findViewById(R.id.button_refresh);

        button_refresh.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        });

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button_copy = findViewById(R.id.button_copy);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> showInfo());
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        downloadJSON();




    }

    private void downloadJSON() {


        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
        class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

                try {
                    settextView(s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("https://www.URL.app/api/tasks.php");
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json).append("\n");
                    }
                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        DownloadJSON getJSON = new DownloadJSON();
        getJSON.execute();
    }

    private void settextView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] tasks = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            tasks[i] = obj.getString("Task_title") + ".\n\n" + obj.getString("task_description");


            textView.setText(tasks[0]);


        }
```

My problem is that I'm not sure where to place the following code:

```
            button_copy.setOnClickListener(v -> {

                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", obj.getString("Task_title") + ".\n\n" + obj.getString("task_description"));
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied to clipboard!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            });
```

I have tried placing it in the settextView, however when I land on the page and the text generates, it automatically copies - but I want this attributed to a button, rather than automatically copying.
For reference, the button in my activity_list.xml is button_copy.

Comment: you can place button copy at the `postExecute`. Show the button copy after the process is finished.

Comment: Thanks for that, but when I place it after e.printStackTrace();   }, it can't find the text:obj goes red - any ideas?

Comment: I updated the answer. Please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more easier, put the button inside the `settextview`. When the process still ongoing, we need to hide/do something with the button. You can hide it on create `.setVisibility` for the button. After that, you can show the button.

```
  private void settextView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] tasks = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            tasks[i] = obj.getString("Task_title") + ".\n\n" + obj.getString("task_description");

        textView.setText(tasks[0]);
        button_copy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Visible it
        setBtnCopyOnClick(tasks[0]); //Here


    }
```

And then make a method for the btn

```
private void setBtnCopyOnClick(String text){
 button_copy.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", text);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied to clipboard!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        });
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the method exactly?  within the settextView? or somewhere else?

Comment: Where part you don't understand. I already commented the info there. @sgccommander

Comment: I'm unsure where to put the btn method.

Comment: 1. replace the method `settextview` with this one. 2. create a method name `setBtnCopyOnClick` 3. Move all codes for `button_copy` inside the method `setBtnCopyOnClick` . @sgccommander

Comment: OK followed your instruction, and when i add the code, it throws up this error: error: unreported exception JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", obj.getString("Task_title") + ".\n\n" + obj.getString("task_description"));

Comment: Sorry mate! Added what you edited, but the obj. turns red: ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", obj.getString("Task_title") + ".\n\n" + obj.getString("task_description"));

Comment: @sgccommander please check carefully my new updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately this just crashes my app :/ If I can message you my full code?

Comment: OK I've got it working! But, you replaced my getString with "text", so all it displays is "text" when copied. I need to it to copy the string...

Comment: @sgccommander Yes it is. since you asked to display only `task[0]`. it will display the 1st array . if it does answer your question, you can tick right

Comment: Oh I see, but when i have it as your latest version (text), the "text" displays in red.

Comment: @sgccommander what does it says the error?

Comment: `error: cannot find symbol
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", text);
                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable text
  location: class activity_tasks

Comment: @sgccommander let TeamViewer. suppose I already answered the question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ticherhaz for getting me there!

Followed his instruction, the issue was incorrect attribute to String, so new code was:

```
    private void setBtnCopyOnClick(String task) {
        Button button_copy = findViewById(R.id.button_copy);
        button_copy.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", task);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied to clipboard!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        });
```